# Typeerror when using S3 and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I've been looking for hours but I can't resolve this problem.

Everything worked fine, until I had to update Carrierwave and use fog-aws gem.

I get the following error only in production when trying to upload an image:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)
```

**My production.rb**

```
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
        config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
        config.fog_credentials = {
          provider: 'AWS',
          aws_access_key_id: 'MYKEY',
          aws_secret_access_key: 'MYKEY',
          region: 'eu-west-1'
        }
        config.permissions = '0666'
        config.fog_directory  = 'sushiartist'
      end
```

**My logs**

```
Processing by ShopsController#update as HTML
2016-09-26T17:15:59.794750+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms
2016-09-26T17:15:59.783946+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VPi4Svgup6sRCNXa1nwZPIIPVb0TY7re9pqQVewl15k=", "shop"=>{"name"=>"Pozas", "city"=>"Bilbao", "phone"=>"94 652 13 99", "direction"=>"Licenciado Poza, 50", "cover"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd15cb0ba00 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160926-3-1efzhcb>, @original_filename="york (1).png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"shop[cover]\"; filename=\"york (1).png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "latitude"=>"43.2625685", "longitude"=>"-2.9425845000000663", "email"=>"", "proximamente"=>"0", "nuevo"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Editar", "id"=>"5"}
```

I'm desperate with, this, any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config.permissions takes an integer not a string.  Change this:

```
config.permissions = '0666'
```

to

```
config.permissions = 0666
```

from https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions = 0666
  config.directory_permissions = 0777
  config.storage = :file
end
```

Comment: Thanks!! I was getting crazy with this!